# Why does my code call the wrong method when there are overloaded methods in the interface

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I have 2 methods:

```
public void WriteRecord(string collectionName, IDatabaseRecord databaseRecord)
public void WriteRecord(string collectionName, BsonDocument bsonDocument)
```

and I include them in my interface:

```
void WriteRecord(string collectionName, BsonDocument bsonDocument);
void WriteRecord(string collectionName, IDatabaseRecord databaseRecord);
```

then when I call;

```
_databaseClient.WriteRecord(Collections.Tracking, workflowTrackingRecord);
```

where **workflowTrackingRecord** is of type **WorkflowInternalTrackingRecord : IDatabaseRecord**

I can see that the code is trying to call the 2nd method ( the one using **BsonDocument** ) because I get this compile error on the line above.:

"The type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MongoDB.Bson..."

If I remove

```
void WriteRecord(string collectionName, IDatabaseRecord databaseRecord);
```

from the interface then

```
_databaseClient.WriteRecord(Collections.Tracking, workflowTrackingRecord);
```

works fine.

Why is the compiler pointing to the wrong method.  What criteria is it using to decide?

Comment: Does `WorkflowInternalTrackingRecord` also inherit from `BsonDocument`?

Comment: No.  And IDatabaseRecord does not inherit from BsonDocument either.

Comment: Well, you'll get that error everywhere you try to work with that Interface and *not* have `MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument` referenced. So the error doesn't prove that the wrong method would be called. Fix the reference and then set a breakpoint in both methods to be sure the wrong one is called.

Comment: Are you saying that if an interface contains a method which uses a type that is unknown to a class that uses the interface then the code won't compile unless the using class has a reference to the type?  If I was not using an interface and just used the concrete class then I wouldn't need to do that.

Comment: You'd probably get away with just using the Interface, but as @Hans Passant explained it way better, when the compiler has to choose which method to use, it needs to know all the involved types. And if it's not referenced, the compiler can't know it. Do you have to use overloading, or could you have something like `WriteRecordBson` and `WriteRecordIDR`? If there is nothing to chose from, the compiler might be happy.

Comment: Yes I get it now.  I've changed the method names.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just haven't gotten that far yet to conclude that the compiler picks the wrong overload.  To determine *which* overload is appropriate, the compiler needs the type info for both BsonDocument and IDatabaseRecord.  But it can't do that, it merely knows BsonDocument exists but doesn't know what it looks like.

Or in other words, the compiler isn't just happy with a perfect candidate, it wants to know *all* of them.  Not so obviously useful in this specific case, but if the overload has any ambiguity then it does get important that you get a good error message as well as avoid the compiler picking the wrong one just because it doesn't know enough about the right one.

Just provide the assembly reference and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I don't want the business layer to know about Mongo and BsonDocuments.  The database client layer knows about them and converts data to my internal objects.

Comment: That has little to do with the question.  Clearly I don't know nearly enough about the coupling, but an interface that BsonDocument implements would work for example.

Comment: I added the reference (but not the using) and the code compiles and uses the correct method.  So the compiler needs to know about the types before it can decide which to use.  I think I'll just rename one of the methods :-)